Power Automate Saving to a Word document using Recorder produces bad formatting
I'm replicating actions that I do routinely, which is opening an EDI application and convert it by generating a print document into a .doc type.
It works beautifully using the Recorder, except when I open the .doc file, it lost it's formatting. I'm not sure what the difference is in the simulation versus doing it manually, but when I do perform the actions manually the formatting isn't lost.
Any suggestions?
